# SELECT by column of type STRING

Tags: abap, opensql

I'll try to explain as simple as possible.

I have a Database table 'DB_JOURNAL' that has only 2 columns 'Date' and 'Journal' type **String**.

example :

```
01.01.2020 | I played football.

02.02.2020 | I played basketball
```

I want to write a Select statement and in the query to search for the **string**.
Like searching for the word football.

```
Select * from DB_JOURNAL into table lt_journal
       where journal like '%football%'.
```

This is not allowed in ABAP:

> The field "JOURNAL" is a long string or a text and cannot be used in the WHERE condition.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What if you remove `into table lt_journal` from the query?

Comment: ```
Select single * from DB_Journal into ls_journal
where journal like '%football'.
```

also doesnt work

Comment: I don't know ABAP but `Select * from table1 into table2` copies the content of table1 to table2. Is that what you REALLY want?

Comment: Actually the selection is more complex and 3 joined tables, i tried to make the example as simple as possible

Comment: @HUJ GMB certainly means `Select * from DB_JOURNAL where journal like '%Football'`

Comment: @C.Champagne, I tried it now, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @SandraRossi, thanks for your input, the example was only to simplify the problem.
My goal is searching a database for a field that has String type, that abap doesn't accept.

Comment: Please add this text to your question, it will help avoid misunderstandings: "When activating this code, I get the error message 'The field "JOURNAL" is a long string or a text and cannot be used in the WHERE condition.' by the compiler. Is there any way to do such a selection without changing the STRING datatype of the database column?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution is to use the [native SQL](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abennative_sql.htm), i.e. the SQL of your database.

Native SQL can be run in several flavors.

The shortest code but also the oldest one (SAP recommends not using it) is with the statement [`EXEC SQL`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapexec.htm):

```
DATA text TYPE string.
EXEC SQL PERFORMING sr.
  SELECT text FROM sotr_textu INTO :text WHERE text LIKE '%e%'
ENDEXEC.
FORM sr.
  WRITE / text.
ENDFORM.
```

NB: the code above works fine with HANA, MSSQL and Oracle databases, but you need to set table and column names in upper case with MaxDB.

**Example of more complex query:**

```
DATA: text   TYPE string,
      status TYPE string.

status = 'R'.

TRY.
    EXEC SQL PERFORMING sr.
      SELECT TEXT FROM SOTR_TEXTU INTO :text
           WHERE  STATUS  = :status
             AND  TEXT    LIKE '%e%'

    ENDEXEC.
  CATCH  cx_sy_native_sql_error INTO DATA(exc).
    cl_demo_output=>display( exc->get_text( ) ).
ENDTRY.
FORM sr.
  WRITE / text.
ENDFORM.
```

**for case-insensitive search:**

```
 AND  UPPER(TEXT) LIKE UPPER(:text)
```

Other ways are [ADBC](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenadbc.htm) and [AMDP](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenamdp.htm).

ADBC has superseded `EXEC SQL`.

Comment: Life saver. 
Thank you so much! I don't know why the compiler didn't accept as I tried it before.
But with this syntax it works!

Comment: SQL inside a `EXEC SQL`/`ENDEXEC` block ("native SQL") is syntactically different from SQL without such a block (ABAP SQL). "Native SQL" is directly interpreted and run by the database, while ABAP SQL is first interpreted by ABAP, which allows only a very limited syntax, and transformed at runtime into SQL which can be understood by the database. **NB: inside a `EXEC SQL`/`ENDEXEC` block, don't enter the classic final dot.**

Comment: Note: Set the table name and the columns in Capital Letters

Comment: @HUJ In lower case, it works well with HANA database. I have added a mention of your own experience.

Comment: I will edit it 1 more time for litte more complex query

Comment: @HUJ Can you edit to mention what database you have please?

Comment: I tried it on 3 different Systems: it worked on MSSQL and Oracle, but not on MaxDB

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid Native SQL which proposed by Sandra is to use looped SELECT:

```
DATA: lt_journal TYPE TABLE OF db_journal WITH EMPTY KEY.

SELECT *
 FROM DB_JOURNAL
 INTO @DATA(wa).
 CHECK wa-journal CP '*football*'.
 APPEND wa TO lt_journal.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe this works with tiny tables, 
but tables with 1M record this will take a while...

Comment: Yep, it depends on your use-case (you simplified your real scenario). If it is selection by only single string field it will take a lot of time, Native SQL/AMDP/ADBC/CDS will be definitely better

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that column "Journal" is of type String?
Can you change it to some existing data element `CHAR40` or something...

Also consider using

`Select * from DB_JOURNAL into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_journal where journal like '%football'.`

Comment: Yes, the challenge is that the column "Journal" is of type String?

Comment: The program doesnt accept this `Select * from DB_JOURNAL into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table lt_journal where journal like '%football'`